# Cant deploy Ingress object on EKS: failed calling webhook vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws: the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am following this AWS guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-fargate/ to setup my kubernetes cluster under ALB.

After installing the AWS ALB controller on my EKS cluster, following below steps:

```sh
helm repo add eks https://aws.github.io/eks-charts
kubectl apply -k "github.com/aws/eks-charts/stable/aws-load-balancer-controller//crds?ref=master"

helm install aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller \
    --set clusterName=YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME \
    --set serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set region=YOUR_REGION_CODE \
    --set vpcId=<VPC_ID> \
    --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller \
    -n kube-system
```

I want to deploy my ingress configurations:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200,302
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: staging
  finalizers:
  - ingress.k8s.aws/resources
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api/v1/price
```

Everything looks fine. However, when I run the below command to deploy my ingress:

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.staging.yaml -n staging
```

I am having below error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.staging.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws": the server could not find the requested resource
```

There are very few similar issues on Google an none was helping me. Any ideas of what is the problem?

K8s version: 1.18

Comment: The the aws-load-balancer-controller pod actually running?

Comment: is this is your first time running it?

Comment: You mentioned that you already tried some solutions. Can you add more details: links, result, etc.? Have you tried this solution: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2039 ?

Answer (score 5):

the security group solved me:

```
node_security_group_additional_rules = {
    ingress_allow_access_from_control_plane = {
      type                          = "ingress"
      protocol                      = "tcp"
      from_port                     = 9443
      to_port                       = 9443
      source_cluster_security_group = true
      description                   = "Allow access from control plane to webhook port of AWS load balancer controller"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the alb controller logs, the CRDs that you are using are for v1beta1 API group while the latest chart is registering v1 API group webhook [aws-load-balancer-controller v2.4.0](https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/pull/695)

If you look at the alb controller startup logs you should see a line similar to the below message

v1beta1

> {"level":"info","ts":164178.5920634,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-networking-v1beta1-ingress"}

v1

> {"level":"info","ts":164683.0114837,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-networking-v1-ingress"}

if that is the case you can fix the problem by using an earlier version of the controller or get the newer version for the CRDs