# Kubernetes API server failed to resolve webhook on EKS with Calico CNI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, calico

I'm trying to deploy an application in AWS EKS. I have created an EKS cluster with Calico CNI by following [the official Calico documentation](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/eks). I have also installed the AWS load balancer controller by following the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/).

Here is my cluster, deployment, and ingress config file.

`cluster.yaml`

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: clustername
  region: us-east-2

nodeGroups:
  - name: ng1
    instanceType: t3.medium
    desiredCapacity: 1
    volumeSize: 30
    maxPodsPerNode: 250
    ami: auto
    ssh:
      publicKeyName: keyname
```

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: my_namspace
  name: deployment-2048
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: alexwhen/docker-2048
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: app-2048
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: my_namspace
  name: service-2048
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
```

`ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my_namspace-ingress
  namespace: my_namspace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: domain.io
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /*
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: service-2048
              port:
                number: 80
```

`kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system -o wide`

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE                                          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
aws-load-balancer-controller-568d85bd58-6jpk5   1/1     Running   0          74m    172.16.22.4     ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
aws-load-balancer-controller-568d85bd58-ph44m   1/1     Running   0          74m    172.16.22.5     ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
calico-kube-controllers-6fd7b9848d-8lw4t        1/1     Running   0          91m    172.16.22.3     ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
calico-node-xdw2h                               1/1     Running   0          87m    192.168.32.46   ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
coredns-f47955f89-5qwh4                         1/1     Running   0          110m   172.16.22.2     ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
coredns-f47955f89-qfpbl                         1/1     Running   0          111m   172.16.22.1     ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-bnw6v                                1/1     Running   0          87m    192.168.32.46   ip-192-168-32-46.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
```

As you can see, everything is running smoothly. The problem is that when I tried to apply my ingress with `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`

`Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress-alb.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws": Post "https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/validate-networking-v1-ingress?timeout=10s": Address is not allowed`

I have learned [from here](https://medium.com/@denisstortisilva/kubernetes-eks-calico-and-custom-admission-webhooks-a2956b49bd0d) that this is a common problem with calico on EKS, and also tried to follow the provided solution of using `hostNetwork: true` in the deployment file as well as in the load balancer controller.

```
helm upgrade aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller \
  -n kube-system \
  --set clusterName=clustername \
  --set serviceAccount.create=false \
  --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller \
  --set hostNetwork=true
```

But the response is the same. Somehow the solution that worked for others doesn't work for me. Perhaps I missed something, I would really love to find that out.

Comment: I found this via google, experiencing the same problem.  But I also found this was part of the problem. Not the whole solution but it did allow the webhooks to start working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72558389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you should not use the **Calico CNI** method along with Amazon EKS service.

Last year, I have spent time looking on this solution and contacted AWS specialist team on resolving a use case with this method. After a while, there is a big **NOTE** on Calico official site as below. I believe that EKS control plane (as well as GKE control plane), both cannot validate the NATed IP address of your pods. The IP range that both Cloud vendors managed control plane are within the VPC.

[image]

Reference: https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/eks

Comment: The only reason I'm pursuing Calico CNI is to save some expenses. My project requires a lunch of multiple small pods that don't require much CPU power. However, due to the pod limitation of AWS VPC, I have no choice but to either go for a higher tier instance which will increase the price per pod, or a CNI such as calico. Do you have any recommendation regarding that?

Comment: If you must use Calico, don't use EKS control plane. You can switch to install your choice of K8s control plane under EC2 using Rancher or something similar. If you continue with EKS, the only way is to use VPC CNI which has 2nd ip addresses limitation of course.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I believe the best option would be to go for VPC CNI in that case. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working by installing the AWS ALB and the ingress in different namespaces.

- Deploy AWS ALB in let's say `kube-system` namespace
- Install your Deployment,Service and Ingress in let's say `myapp` namespace. Deployment,Service and Ingress all listening on 8080 and connecting with a PGSQL RDS on 5432.
- Install Calico in its own namespace
- Install deny-default policy in `myapp` namespace
- Install custom network policy in `myapp` namespace with port 8080 and 5432 ingress and all egress allowed.

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "allow_http_pgsql" {
  metadata {
    name      = "allow-http-pgsql"
    namespace = "myapp"
  }

  spec {
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "myapp"
      }
    }
    ingress {
      ports {
        port     = "8080"
        protocol = "TCP"
      }
      ports {
        port     = "5432"
        protocol = "TCP"
      }
    }
    egress {}
    policy_types = ["Ingress", "Egress"]
  }
}
```

To be honest my use-case here was to restrict network connections in a specific namespace i.e. `myapp` and not all namespaces.